# reactjs - bootstrap: input width within table same for all columns irrespective of column contents

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am creating a bootstrap table in reactjs. The table has a filter below each column heading.

the following is the code:

```
<table className="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th onClick={() => this.handleColumnSort("id")}><b>Id</b> <i className={`fa fa-fw ${this.handleColumnSortCss("id")}`}></i></th>
      <th onClick={() => this.handleColumnSort("name")}><b>Name</b> <i className={`fa fa-fw ${this.handleColumnSortCss("name")}`}></i></th>
      <th onClick={() => this.handleColumnSort("munit")}><b>Munit</b> <i className={`fa fa-fw ${this.handleColumnSortCss("munit")}`}></i></th>
      <th onClick={() => this.handleColumnSort("rate")}><b>Rate</b> <i className={`fa fa-fw ${this.handleColumnSortCss("rate")}`}></i></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><input  type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler("id",e)}/></th>
      <th><input  type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler("name",e)}/></th>
      <th><input  type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler("munit",e)}/></th>
      <th><input  type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler("rate",e)}/></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {this.props.items.filtereditems.map((item,index) => (
    <tr key={index} >
        <th> {(index+1)+((this.props.page_number-1)*(this.props.page_size))}</th>
        <td> {item.id}</td>
        <td> {item.name}</td>
        <td> {item.munit}</td>
        <td> {item.rate}</td>
    </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the output is:
[image]

But without the input it looks much better, It auto adjusts to the content width.

[image]

So how to achieve the above layout with input widths not expanding to max.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,you just need to add Css styling to your `<input />` fixed width or Padding.
[css box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired result making the name column `width: 100%`.

The name column could be wider, which in turn would make the other columns smaller, while respecting fluid widths.

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Munit</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As an example, you could target the name column like so:

```
table th:nth-child(3),
table td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This also assumes the following rule is in effect on the table element:

```
table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49fach5w/

As you mentioned you use boostrap, you can use the following helper class:

`w-100`

You can apply this to each table cell that contains 'name' data, for example:

`<th class="w-100">...</th>`

Comment: Isn't possible without mentioning colspan. Because its autospanning without input, problem occurs when we add input

Comment: `table th:nth-child(3),table td:nth-child(3){width: 100%;} ` what is the magic behind this

Comment: I don't think it's the best way to apply this rule but without seeing your CSS, it's just an example of targeting the third column in your table. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

Comment: I dont have any css files. I am just using bootstrapv4. I want to know the reason why input is not fitting as per the columns

Comment: HTML tables will also try and fit all of the columns within the table, so even though we have claimed that the 'name' column should be 100% width, it can't actually do this - as it needs to fit the other columns within the table boundaries. So what this really does, is makes the third column fill as much width as it can, and then automatically distribute the remaining space to the other columns in the table (giving them the bare minimum width they need to fit).

Comment: so there is no default solution other than css styling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159477/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-danb).